# Condensing contact query code

Tags: android, android-contacts

I've got this code here that gets and sets the contact's pic, all phone numbers, all emails, and all addresses for a predetermined contact_id.  Works fine, but I'm sure there's a simpler way.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ContactDetailsTest extends Activity {

    ListView contactDetails;
    TextView tvContactName;
    TextView tvType;
    ImageView ivContactPic;
    ArrayList<ContactItemDetails> details;
    ContactDetailsAdapter adapter;
    // Extras passed from contact name list
    String contactId;
    String contactName;
    // Content list query args
    Uri uri;
    String[] projection, selectionArgs;
    String selection, sortOrder;
    Executor executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contactinfotest);
        ivContactPic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivContactPic);
        contactId = getIntent().getStringExtra("contactId");
        contactName = getIntent().getStringExtra("contactName");
        tvContactName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvContactName);        
        tvContactName.setText(contactName);
        tvType = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvDetailType);


        long contact_Id = Long.parseLong(contactId);
        final Bitmap my_btmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(openDisplayPhoto(contact_Id));
        ivContactPic.setImageBitmap(my_btmp);

        contactDetails = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contactDetailsList);
        details = new ArrayList<ContactItemDetails>();
        adapter = new ContactDetailsAdapter(details, this);
        contactDetails.setAdapter(adapter);

        Runnable phoneRun = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {                 
                uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
                projection = null;
                selection = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                        + " = " + contactId;
                selectionArgs = null;
                sortOrder = null;
                Cursor phoneCursor = getContentResolver().query(uri,
                        projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
                if (phoneCursor != null && phoneCursor.getCount() > 0) {
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            ContactItemDetails contactItemDetails = new ContactItemDetails();
                            contactItemDetails.setNumber("Phone");
                            details.add(contactItemDetails);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });
                    while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                        final ContactItemDetails contactItemDetails = new ContactItemDetails();
                        if (Integer
                                .parseInt(phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor
                                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                            String number = phoneCursor
                                    .getString(phoneCursor
                                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                            int type = phoneCursor
                                    .getInt(phoneCursor
                                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
                            String customLabel = phoneCursor
                                    .getString(phoneCursor
                                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LABEL));
                            String phoneLabel = (String) ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone
                                    .getTypeLabel(ContactDetailsTest.this
                                            .getResources(), type, customLabel);
                            contactItemDetails.setNumber(number);
                            contactItemDetails.setType(phoneLabel);
                            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    details.add(contactItemDetails);
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (phoneCursor != null) {
                    phoneCursor.close();
                }
                uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI;
                projection = null;
                selection = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID
                        + " = " + contactId;
                selectionArgs = null;
                sortOrder = null;
                Cursor emailCursor = getContentResolver().query(uri,
                        projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
                if (emailCursor != null && emailCursor.getCount() > 0) {
                    final ContactItemDetails ItemDetails = new ContactItemDetails();
                    ItemDetails.setNumber("Email");
                    ItemDetails.setType("----------");
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            details.add(ItemDetails);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });
                    while (emailCursor.moveToNext()) {
                        final ContactItemDetails contactItemDetails = new ContactItemDetails();
                        String eAddress = emailCursor
                                .getString(emailCursor
                                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS));
                        int type = emailCursor
                                .getInt(emailCursor
                                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE));
                        String customLabel = emailCursor
                                .getString(emailCursor
                                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.LABEL));
                        String emailLabel = (String) ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email
                                .getTypeLabel(
                                        ContactDetailsTest.this.getResources(),
                                        type, customLabel);
                        contactItemDetails.setNumber(eAddress);
                        contactItemDetails.setType(emailLabel);
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                details.add(contactItemDetails);
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
                if (emailCursor != null) {
                    emailCursor.close();
                }
                uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_URI;
                projection = null;
                selection = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTACT_ID
                        + " = " + contactId;
                selectionArgs = null;
                sortOrder = null;
                Cursor addCursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection,
                        selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
                if (addCursor != null && addCursor.getCount() > 0) {
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            ContactItemDetails contactItemDetails = new ContactItemDetails();
                            contactItemDetails.setNumber("Address");
                            contactItemDetails.setType("----------");
                            details.add(contactItemDetails);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });
                    while (addCursor.moveToNext()) {
                        final ContactItemDetails contactItemDetails = new ContactItemDetails();
                        String address = addCursor
                                .getString(addCursor
                                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.FORMATTED_ADDRESS));
                        int type = addCursor
                                .getInt(addCursor
                                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE));
                        String customLabel = addCursor
                                .getString(addCursor
                                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.LABEL));
                        String addLabel = (String) ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal
                                .getTypeLabel(
                                        ContactDetailsTest.this.getResources(),
                                        type, customLabel);
                        contactItemDetails.setNumber(address);
                        contactItemDetails.setType(addLabel);
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                details.add(contactItemDetails);
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
                if (addCursor != null) {
                    addCursor.close();
                }
            }
        };
        executor.execute(phoneRun);
    }

    public InputStream openDisplayPhoto(long contact_Id) {
        contact_Id = Long.parseLong(contactId);
        Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contact_Id);
        Uri displayPhotoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.DISPLAY_PHOTO);
        try {
            AssetFileDescriptor fd = getContentResolver()
                    .openAssetFileDescriptor(displayPhotoUri, "r");
            return fd.createInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts.Entity and android.provider.ContactsContract.RawContacts.Entity.

Answer (score 0):

try doing it via intents:

```
Uri sendUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(path,name.getText().toString()+".png"));
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
                        intent.setDataAndType(sendUri, "image/png");
                        intent.putExtra("mimeType", "image/png");
                        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Set As"), 200);
                        Intent i= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT);;
                         i.setType(Contacts.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
                          i.putExtra(Insert.NAME, name.getText().toString());
                          i.putExtra(Insert.PHONE, phno.getText().toString());
                          startActivity(i);
```